# validateOptions is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, enzyme

FAIL  src/pages/trade/trade-sagas/trade-sagas.unit.test.js

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'axios' from 'src/pages/trade/trade-sagas/trade-sagas.unit.test.js'

  1 | import { runSaga } from "redux-saga";
> 2 | import axios from "axios";
    | ^
  3 | import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
  4 | import tradeActions from "../trade-actions/trade-actions";
  5 | import requestObj from "../../../utils/request/request";
```

at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
at Object. (src/pages/trade/trade-sagas/trade-sagas.unit.test.js:2:1)

I came accross the above error while running my tests. Then I decided to install Axios `npm install axios-mock-adapter --save-dev`
After installing and rerunning my app `npm start` I came across this error: `validateOptions is not a function`

I have tried uninstalling the same package but I am still getting the error! Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You can install Axios like this without the following npm install Axios-mock-adapter, npm install axios

Comment: The main problem is not how to install Axios but how to get rid of the error!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above error by deleting my lock files, node modules and then running `yarn install`. After that, I ran `run yarn add axios-mock-adapter`
Then finally `yarn start` worked perfectly.
I hope this will help someone someday out there.
Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get things to work just by deleting the node_modules and reinstalling it.